# createElement creates infinite loop

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, createelement

I'm really new to javascript, and coding in general, and I can't understand why this causes an infinite loop:

```
  let newTr = document.createElement('tr');
```

If I take it out, the webpage loads fine, but if I leave it in, the webpage never fully loads and my browser uses 50% of my CPU.

Here's the rest of my code:

```
// client-side js
// run by the browser each time your view template referencing it is loaded

console.log('hello world :o');

let arrPfcCases = [];

// define variables that reference elements on our page

const tablePfcCases = document.getElementById("tablePfcCases");
const formNewPfcCase = document.forms[0];
const caseTitle = formNewPfcCase.elements['caseTitle'];
const caseMOI = formNewPfcCase.elements['caseMOI'];
const caseInjuries = formNewPfcCase.elements['caseInjuries'];

// a helper function to call when our request for case is done
const  getPfcCaseListener = function() {
  // parse our response to convert to JSON
  arrPfcCases = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  // iterate through every case and add it to our page
  for (var i = 0; i = arrPfcCases.length-1;i++) {
    appendNewCase(arrPfcCases[i]);
  };
}

// request the dreams from our app's sqlite database
const pfcCaseRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
pfcCaseRequest.onload = getPfcCaseListener;
pfcCaseRequest.open('get', '/getDreams');
pfcCaseRequest.send();

// a helper function that creates a list item for a given dream
const appendNewCase = function(pfcCase) {
  if (pfcCase != null) {
  tablePfcCases.insertRow();
  let newTr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i = pfcCase.length - 1; i++) {
    let newTd = document.createElement('td');
    let newText = document.createTextNode(i.value);
    console.log(i.value);
    newTd.appendChild(newText);
    newTr.appendChild(newTd);
  }

  tablePfcCases.appendChild(newTr);
  }
}

// listen for the form to be submitted and add a new dream when it is
formNewPfcCase.onsubmit = function(event) {
  // stop our form submission from refreshing the page
  event.preventDefault();
  let newPfcCase = [caseTitle, caseMOI, caseInjuries];
  // get dream value and add it to the list
  arrPfcCases.push(newPfcCase);
  appendNewCase(newPfcCase);

  // reset form 
  formNewPfcCase.reset;

};
```

Thanks!

P.S. There are probably a ton of other things wrong with the code, I just can't do anything else until I figure this out!

Comment: `i = pfcCase.length - 1` should be `i < pfcCase.length`

Comment: `If I take it out` you'll get an error (do you know your browser has a **developer** tools console - where errors are shown for your debugging pleasure?) on `newTr.appendChild(newTd)` which is why your for loop won't go on forever for the reason given above

Comment: Andy, that fixed it! 

I have no idea why (the line isn't even in the for loop), but it works when I made that change.

Thanks!!!

Comment: `I have no idea why` - did you read my comment and look in the developer tools console?

Comment: Jaromanda, I knew I was getting an error on the newTr.appendChild(newTd) when I took out the line in question, that wasn't the problem.  If I left the problem line in, it would cause the loop.  

Aslo, I did know about the console, it wasn't even loading though! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an explanation, in your code

```
i = pfcCase.length - 1
```

assigned the value of `pfcCase.length - 1` to `i`. The syntax of that part of the loop should be

> [an expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Syntax) If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed.

The evaluation of your code made no sense.

Evaluating

```
i < pfCase.length
```

before each iteration to check that the current index is less than the length of the array, however, works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is no conditional statement here. In this statement you are assigning pfcCase length minus 1 to the I variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i = pfcCase.length - 1; i++) {
```

You have to compare the i variable to the length of the pfcCase minus 1.

This should work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < pfcCase.length - 1; i++) {
```

### noticed something else

This line does not do what you think it dose.

```
let newText = document.createTextNode(i.value);
```

i is just the index i.e. a number. It does not have the value property.

This is what you are looking to do.

```
let newText = document.createTextNode(pfcCase[i].value);
```

### my preference (forEach)

I prefer using the array forEach method. It’s cleaner and less prone to mistakes.

```
pfcCase.forEach( function(val){
    let newTd = document.createElement('td');
    let newText = document.createTextNode(val.value);
    console.log('The array element is. '. val.value, ' The value is. ', val.value);
    newTd.appendChild(newText);
    newTr.appendChild(newTd);
  });
```